# Call to MySQL cursor.execute() (Python driver) hangs

Tags: python, mysql

I'm using a python driver (mysql.connector) and do the following:

```
_db_config = {
  'user': 'root',
  'password': '1111111',
  'host': '10.20.30.40',
  'database': 'ddb'
}
```

- `_connection = mysql.connector.connect(**_db_config) # connect to a remote server`
- `_cursor = _connection.cursor(buffered=True)`
- `_cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM database LIMIT 1;""")`

In some cases, the call to _cursor.execute() **hangs** with no exception

By the way, when connecting to a local MySQL server it seems to be ok

Comment: remove `;` from the third line

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ I thought at first that it solve my issue here but unfortunately it isn't. I still get those hangs and the timeout is not solving it either :-(

Comment: The SQL query in itself is not something that consumes that time ... Do you observe the same thing when you run the query directly from the command line?

Comment: I get these issues if I run it from IPython or Jupyter. Running it as python file pass ok. Another thing is that using a local server (usually I'm connecting to remote server) works ok as well, so the problem must be with the remote connection

Comment: In my case table was missing in the database. And cursor was not giving any error message.

Answer (score 0):

The result might hang due to large databases or not optimized queries.
you can try following things

- optimize your query
- use a better connector driver
  I generally use python3.x and for this I either use "pymysql" or "pypyodbc"
  which are new and optimized drivers

here is a post to work with "pymysql" [Gives small idea to with with mysql and python3](https://makcs.blogspot.in/2016/02/python3x-database-connectivity-with.html)

Comment: I doubt the query is too big because OP is using LIMIT 1 and is asking for a wild card.  That shouldn't be too much right?

Answer (score -1):

Moving to MySQLdb (instead of mysql.connector) solved all the issues :-)